# Determine if a list group item has been unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal window, and in it I have a bootstrap list-group-item of buttons. In my jquery/js I enable a submit button when one of the button is clicked, but if I click somewhere else on the modal window the button gets unchecked! How can I look for this event so that I can disable my submit button?
Or can I prevent the button from getting unchecked if I press somewhere else on the modal window?

Here is my modal window.

```js
$(".removeReason").off('click').on('click', function() {
  $("#removeMember").prop('disabled', false);
});

// I need a .removeReason event that gets triggered when any button is unchecked
```

```html
<div id="removeMemberModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">@(ViewBag.IsTeacher == true ? "Remove Teacher" : "Remove Student")</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          <h4>Why do you want to remove this @(ViewBag.IsTeacher == true ? "Teacher" : "Student")</h4>
        </p>
        <p>
          <div class="list-group">
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item removeReason">Bad Reviews</button>
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item removeReason">Made offensive comment</button>
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item removeReason">Shows up late or misses class altogether</button>
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item removeReason">Would like to register a different @(ViewBag.IsTeacher == true ? "Teacher" : "Student")</button>
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item removeReason">Other</button>
          </div>
        </p>
        <p>
          @if(ViewBag.IsTeacher == true) {
          <div>The teacher and all registered students will be notified by email that he/she has been removed from this event.</div>
          } else {
          <div>The student will be notified that he/she has been removed from this event.</div>
          }
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="removeMember" data-member-id=@ViewBag.MemberId type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an active class to each button that gets pressed.
like so

```js
$(".removeReason").off('click').on('click', function() {
  $(".removeReason").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("#removeMember").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution you find but take a look of this `.toggleClass` method :) http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$(".removeReason").click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass("active");
});
```